# Reloading another PHP into a DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've read countless articles regarding replacing a `<div>` with other content more specifically another PHP file.  I cannot seem to get this to work. When I click either buttons absolutely nothing happens. I tried to ensure that all the id="XXX" are correct for all  and the JavaScript function but I'm new to Javascript. I have included the code below and links to both the page I attempting to put this in and a test page.

Orginal Page - http://www.havenswatch.com/records/player.php?playerID=1

Test Page - http://www.havenswatch.com/records/testdivswap.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadbioPage() {
                $("#rightpage").load('bio.php');
            }
            function loadcreditsPage(){
                $("#rightpage").load('creditsmod.php');
            }
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Bio" onclick="loadbioPage()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Credits" onclick="loadcreditsPage()"/>
        <div id="rightpage">
            <?php include('creditsmod.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Both the bio.php and creditsmod.php use $variables from the original page", you mean that you use variables from the page shown to run a query on the `.load` pages? because you would need to pass those variables appropriately if so.

Comment: Your test page is not including jQuery, that's probably a decent place to start.

Comment: You need to use session variables. Regular PHP variables are not shared between pages.

Comment: I apparently didn't confused some of you on my question. That question honestly has nothing to do with passing the $variables between pages. I will edit my post I was a bit frustrated when I posted sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Include jQuery and use proper event handlers, if you need help with outputting the right data in your PHP scripts, show us the scripts and ask a question :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#loadbioPage').on('click', function() {
                $("#rightpage").load('bio.php');
            });

            $('#loadcreditsPage').on('click', function() {
                $("#rightpage").load('creditsmod.php');
            });
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" value="Bio" id="loadbioPage"/>
     <input type="button" value="Credits" id="loadcreditsPage"/>
     <div id="rightpage">
         <?php include('creditsmod.php'); ?>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even better, `<... class='load' data-page="...">` then `$('.load').click(..);`

Comment: @PaoloBergantino - why is it better, it takes more effort to look up classes and data attributes then a single ID ?

Comment: @adeneo, Paolo's suggestion makes it more modular, and therefore more extensible, at the cost of some efficiency. Whichever one is '*better*' probably depends on the circumstance and the programmer's goals.

Comment: @adeneo: At two buttons it's probably just a preference thing, but once you get up to 3 or more buttons the minuscule cost of getting the elements by class instead of ID is well worth how much easier it would be to maintain.

Comment: @jmeas - I'll agree with classes and data attributes being more modular, and can be extended with as many elements you'd like, however for simplicity and showing how it works to a newbie, the above solution is better IMO, and it is of course more efficient

Comment: Thank you all for you input, Obviously I was a tard thinking jquery already implemented. I apologize for my idiotic question I was to focused elsewhere to realize that.

Comment: @adeneo: On the contrary, one of the things that newbies struggle with the most when using jQuery is the concept of using classes for "one of many" and abstracting out their code when possible to avoid repeating things over and over. This is a pretty perfect example to show someone new. The efficiency edge is basically worthless.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino can you elaborate some on what you mean by the       <...      class='load' data-page="..."> then $('.load').click(..); – in just a tiny example.

Comment: @Warmour - he means you could do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usvdN/4/) to make it work even if you added ten more buttons etc !

Comment: Ahh, so I could use one function and just add the file to be loaded to the actual button. Got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well your using jquery methods but Idon't see jquery being mentioned in the head. also you should probably clear the div first an example script below of what I would do to achieve this.

```
<html>
<head>

//reference jquery
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                                          
<script type="text/javascript">

//make sure the document is ready for changes
$(document).ready(function(){

//listen for btn 1 to be clicked
$('#btn1').click(function(){
$('#rightpage').html(""); //clear html inside the div so new content can replace it
$('#rightpage').load('creditsmod.php'); //load new data
});

//listen for btn 2 to be clicked    
$('#btn2').click(function(){
$('#rightpage').html(""); //clear html inside the div so new content can replace it
$('#rightpage').load('bio.php'); //load new data
});

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1">CreditsMod</button> //great html5 option compared to input for buttons.
<button id="btn2">Bio</button>
<div id="rightpage"><?php include('creditsmod.php'); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Firebug consol shows error in the  tag.

Try the below code

```
  <html>
 <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function loadbioPage(){
   $("#rightpage").load('bio.php');
}
 function loadcreditsPage(){
 $("#rightpage").load('creditsmod.php');
}
</script>    
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Bio" onclick="javascript:loadbioPage(); return false;"/>
 <input type="button" value="Credits" onclick="javascript:loadcreditsPage(); return false;"/>
 <div id="rightpage">
     <?php include('creditsmod.php'); ?>
 </div>
```

The rest of the code seems fine.

Please check it.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
<script>
function loadbioPage(){
$("#rightpage").load('bio.php');
}
function loadcreditsPage(){
$("#rightpage").load('creditsmod.php');
}
</script>
```

// please check the opening of script tag in our code and install jQuery latest version.